# Can I detect fullscreen in a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, fullscreen, content-script

I have a Chrome extension (specifically, a "content script") where I'd like to detect whether the page I am monitoring/changing is in fullscreen state. I have tried several APIs, as well as the "screenfull" library, but no luck so far. Any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to detect whether the page has **used the Fullscreen API** to enter fullscreen mode, just check `document.webkitIsFullscreen`.

If you want a general method to reliably detect full screen mode, the [`chrome.windows`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html) API is your only option. Since this API is unavailable to content scripts, you need to use the [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) API to interact with a [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) or [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html).

#### Example: [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)

```js
function isFullScreen(callback) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage('getScreenState', function(result) {
        callback(result === 'fullscreen');
    });
}
// Example: Whenever you want to know the state:
isFullScreen(function(isFullScreen) {
    alert('Window is ' + (isFullScreen ? '' : 'not ') + 'in full screen mode.');
});
```

#### Example: [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) / [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message === 'getScreenState') {
        chrome.windows.get(sender.tab.windowId, function(chromeWindow) {
            // "normal", "minimized", "maximized" or "fullscreen"
            sendResponse(chromeWindow.state);
        });
        return true; // Signifies that we want to use sendResponse asynchronously
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
var isFullScreen = (screen.width == window.outerWidth) && (screen.height == window.outerHeight);
if(isFullScreen) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to listen for `webkitfullscreenchange` event, e.g

```
$(document).on('webkitfullscreenchange',function(){
  if (document.webkitIsFullScreen === true) {
    console.log('Full screen mode is on");
  } else {
    console.log('Full screen mode is off");
  }
});
```